# display() function causes runtime error

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort, display

I have implemented a `static linkedList mergeSort (linkedList one)` method  that sorts a linkedList recursively and works.

Here is the method that is defined in my `linkedList.h`:

```
linkedList linkedList::mergeSort(linkedList& one)
{
    if (one.head->next == NULL)
    {
        return one;
    }
    else
    {
        linkedList right;
        linkedList::split(one, right);
        right = mergeSort(right);
        one = mergeSort(one);
        linkedList sort;
        linkedList::merge(one, right, sort);
        one = sort;
        return one;
    }
}
```

When I display it, it prints out correctly to the screen so I know it works but if the `linkedList` is bigger than 4505 nodes, it won't print. I debugged to check where the problem was. Apparently it is in my display function but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Here it is:

```
void display(node * p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        display(p->next);
    }
}
```

The problem is pointed to `cout << p->data << " ";`

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to fix this? (If it can be fixed at all.) Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: calling a recursive function 4505 time is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a recursive function for 4505 times, implement your code with while loop:

```
void display(node * p)
{
    while(p != NULL)
    {
       cout<<p->data<<" ";
       p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: your terminal will like you better with a `endl` after the loop

Comment: @GeoffreyB this is how OP implemented in his code and I preserved that but totally agree with you